# Ошибка "Файл не найден" Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Написал несложную программу на с++ в Qt Creator. Программа работала. Вчера я решил ее усовершенствовать и открыл этот проект. Все запустилось как было. Потом я исправил одну-пару чисел в коде (вариант с которыми я тоже до этого пробовал, все должно работать исправно). После этого я получаю такую ошибку (проект называется BigNumber):

> :-1: ошибка: ..BigNumbermain.cpp: No such file or directory
>
> :-1: ошибка: no input files

Вывод консоли сборки:

> 11:10:11: Выполняется сборка проекта BigNumber...
>   11:10:11: Запускается: «C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.4.1\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe» clean
>   C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Debug clean
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/BigNumber-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4__4_7_4_________'
>   del debug\main.o debug\bignumber.o debug\mvector.o
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/BigNumber-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4__4_7_4_________'
>   C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Release clean
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, del debug\main.o debug\bignumber.o debug\mvector.o, ...) failed.
>   make (e=2): Не удается найти указанный файл.
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: [clean] Error 2 (ignored)
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/BigNumber-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4__4_7_4_________'
>   del release\main.o release\bignumber.o release\mvector.o
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/BigNumber-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4__4_7_4_________'
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, del release\main.o release\bignumber.o release\mvector.o, ...) failed.
>   make (e=2): Не удается найти указанный файл.
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: [clean] Error 2 (ignored)
>   11:10:12: Процесс «C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.4.1\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe» завершился нормально.
>   11:10:12: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
>   11:10:12: Запускается: «C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.4.1\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe» 
>   C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Debug
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/BigNumber-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4__4_7_4_________'
>   g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I"..\BigNumber" -I"." -I"..\..\4.7.4\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\BigNumber\main.cpp
>   g++.exe: ..BigNumbermain.cpp: No such file or directory
>   g++.exe: no input files
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/BigNumber-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4__4_7_4_________'
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 1
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
>   11:10:13: Процесс «C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.4.1\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
>   Возникла ошибка при сборке проекта BigNumber (цель: Desktop)
>   Во время выполнения сборки на этапе «Сборка»

Не пойму в чем дело, но точно не в этих числах, которые я изменил. При возврате выходит тоже самое. Думаю, я случайно куда-то нажал. Может в файле .pro что-нибудь удалил? Файл .pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
bignumber.cpp \
mvector.cpp

HEADERS += \
bignumber.h \
mvector.h
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти проблему. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Нигде не встречается `BigNumbermain.cpp`? Пробовали почистить сгенерированные файлы?

Comment: `BigNumber` - это папка? Если где-то у вас встречается путь вроде `BigNumber\main.cpp`, попробуйте написать `BigNumber\\main.cpp`. Потом запустите qmake и пересоберите проект.

Comment: А еще лучше `BigNumber/main.cpp`